# Is it possible to put a header column on the right of a table in Pages?

Tags: pages

I only see an option to place the header column on the left side of a table in Pages. Is there an option to make a header column (footer column?) on the *right* side of a table?

Answer (score 2):

I did *not* think this would actually work.

Apparently, if you switch to a RTL language before inserting a table, it automatically orients it right-to-left instead of the default left-to-right.

It's annoying that this doesn't help for tables already created, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: C'mon, Apple! This is a silly way to have to do things!